# Добавление вспомогательных файлов в проект

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-code, .net-core

Есть C# проект. В нём используется набор различных вспомогательных файлов типа XML документов, схем и прочее, необходимое для работы проекта. Все эти вспомогательные файлы и есть часть проекта, они с ним тесно связаны, хранятся с ним в гите и так далее.

Первая попытка была - кинуть каталог с этими файлами в корень проекта (добавить всё в гит и прочее), а в проекте обращаться к ним, используя `Environment.CurrentDirectory`. Но оказалось мало того, что VisualStudio и VSCode возвращают разные значения, так VS возвращает путь куда-то `./bin/...`, а не корень.

Так вот...
Как всё это правильно в проект добавить и как ко всему этому правильно в проекте обращаться?

Comment: appdata и у каждого файлика выставить свойство Content для режима компиляции